# julia-lang - using Colors.jl arrays with PyPlot commands

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I am trying to assign an RGB tuple generated with distinguishable_colors from Colors.jl to an specific line with pyplot in Julia lang, for instance:

```
using PyPlot, Colors
RGB_1 = distinguishable_colors(10)[5]
plot(linspace(1,10,10), color=RGB_1)
```

But it seems the rgb space colors are not suitable for the plot:

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "<PyCall.jlwrap RGB{U8}(0.0,0.0,0.0)>"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "<PyCall.jlwrap RGB{U8}(0.0,0.0,0.0)>"
cannot convert argument to rgb sequence
```

Is there anyway to get the tuple (0.0,0.0,0.0) from the Colors.jl generated arrays, instead of the RGB{U8}(0.0,0.0,0.0)? I noticed that

```
plot(linspace(1,10,10), color=(0.0,0.0,0.0))
```

does work. Julia 0.3.2 with matplotlib 1.4.2.

Comment: `rgb1v = map(x->Float64(getfield(RGB_1,x)),fieldnames(RGB_1))` returns a Vector of Float64s. To use in `plot`, `color=(rgb1v...)` should work. But my Julia version is 0.5, so your mileage may vary. 0.3 should not really be used anymore. Upgrade to 0.5 (or 0.4 if you must) as Julia is changing and you want to change with it!

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your answer. I got the following error with your code: `rgb1v = map(x->Float64(getfield(RGB_1,x)),fieldnames(RGB_1))
ERROR: type cannot be constructed
 in anonymous at ./none:1
 in map at ./abstractarray.jl:1328` As per the version, I agree but debian stable handle this version of Julia...

Comment: Install the most recent generic linux binary from the official Julia downloads page then, just download, untar and run.  v0.3 support will be droped out ASAP if it hasn't already been officially droped yet.

Comment: @LeandroAcquaroli change the `Float64` in the line to `float64` (in lowercase). This works in 0.3 (checked it in JuliaBox sandbox - +1 to cloud computers and containers).

Comment: @DanGetz Thanks. Confirmed that works changing to lower case.

Comment: @IsmaelVenegasCastelló Will try that option too as the Julia version is way too old in the stable branch. Thanks!

Comment: @IsmaelVenegasCastelló Just tried the binary julia-0.4.6 and I get the same error with the RGB space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the `color` option of the `plot` function a tuple of 3 `UFixed8` (which is an alias for `FixedPointNumbers.UFixed{UInt8,8}`). `Colors.jl` has the following functions `red`, `green` and `blue` to get each respective field from an `RGB` type, each one of `UFixed8` type:

```rb
julia> VERSION
v"0.4.6"

julia> using PyPlot, Colors

julia> rgb₁ = distinguishable_colors(10)[5]
RGB{U8}(0.843,0.267,0.0)

julia> rgb_sequence(c::RGB) = (red(c), green(c), blue(c))
rgb (generic function with 1 method)

julia> rgb₁_tuple = rgb_sequence(rgb₁)
(UFixed8(0.843),UFixed8(0.267),UFixed8(0.0))

julia> eltype(rgb₁_tuple)
FixedPointNumbers.UFixed{UInt8,8}

julia> plot(linspace(1, 10, 10), color = rgb₁_tuple)
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 PyObject <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x000000002864E240>
```

Out:

[image]

Tested on `v"0.3.12"` also. The only difference is that `RGB₁ = distinguishable_colors(10)[5]` returns a different color (`RGB{U8}(0.0,0.522,1.0)`) in my case.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm this method also works in v0.3.2.

Comment: @LeandroAcquaroli if my answers solves your question, don't forget to mark it as the answer, thanks!